# Dr. Bronner's soap

Tags: translation, shemos-sacred-names, shema, kedusha-holiness, personal-hygiene

If you read the [label](http://all-one-typography.com/) of a bottle of Dr. Bronner's soap you will find--as I was flabbergasted to find--that the very last words are a whimsical English translation of "Shema Yisroel."

Dr. Bronner was the son of two Orthodox Holocaust victims HY"D. He had a very interesting mind.

The actual text on the bottle is "Listen Children Eternal Father Eternally One!"

- Must Dr. Bronner's Soap stay out of the bathroom because it contains the text of a pasuk? (re: Berachot 26)
- Is the bottle sheimos?

Comment: I've actually wondered this myself. Depending on the bottle, I think, it also contains some strange other text that may or may not pose problems (being derived from christian scripture)...

Comment: That's why the line sounds familiar! I didn't realize it was supposed to be Shma.

Comment: if somthing was made with the intention of it being used in a disgraceful fashion such as being brought into the bathroom then it doesnt have any significance

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44200/is-there-a-halachic-problem-with-the-columbia-university-seal-on-the-floor-of-th

Comment: He actually broks a huge number of pesukim on there, not just Shema Yisroel

Answer (score 4):

Earlier on the label it mentions Jesus being a student of Hillel. That makes this label a work of a min. Even torah scrolls written by minim lack holiness and dont go into shemos.

Source later.

Comment: This is a very interesting begining of answer. But if you give a proof that saying that JC is a student of Hillel makes the speaker a min this is even better. Gemara said he was a student of Yehoshua Ben Perachia  and that he became a min.

Comment: The statement suggests that Jesus was less of a renegade, legitimizing him. It  many not make one a bona fida min for the purposes of a Kefira conviction, but it is certainly min-ish.

Comment: yes I agree min_ish

Comment: Related to this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16273/heretics-in-the-bathroom?rq=1

Comment: @Clinteastwood Would it have been better if he had said Jesus was a student of Yehoshua ben Perachia? (That, as far as I know, is true)

Comment: The Jesus being a student of yehoshua Ben prachya was not during the same time period as the Jesus in christianity