# What is the view of Judaism or majority Jews towards Islam?

Tags: islam

Islam claim to know Abrahamic religion or Judaism, whatever it is, better than Jews themselves. What is the view of the majority Jews in this matter? *(I hope this fits the site guidelines)*

Comment: Are you asking if Judaism thinks Islam is a better religion than Judaism?

Comment: Hi, Mawia. I have voted to close this question, because I don't think that there is really much to say about this question. Put simply, if Jews believed that Muslims have a better understanding of our religion than Muslims do, then they'd be Muslims rather than Jews. If you could edit this question to ask something more specific, that would be better.

Comment: @DoubleAA Nope. Likely the opposite.

Comment: Also, just to help you out a little bit, Jews today do not even try to claim that we practice our religion the same way that Abraham did.

Comment: I think the confusion here is with the Abrahamic thing. Let me try to make it more simple.

Comment: I just want to know what is the view of Jews towards Islam. I don't know what more to say or how to say. You may edit it to make it more understandable for yourselves.

Comment: @Mawia The Jewish view of what part of Islam? Are you asking about [Jews converting to Islam](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28390/1713), or maybe [whether praying to the Muslim concept of God is the same as praying to the Jewish concept of God](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/1713), or maybe something else?

Comment: Looks like no one is understanding or I'm not understanding anything. I give up. I'm leaving this place. Bye...

Comment: Hi @Mawia.  I'm sorry this is causing difficulty, but I'm still having trouble understanding what you're asking.  Your comment to DoubleAA suggests that you're *not* asking "what does Judaism think about Islam's claim of superiority?", but that's how the question reads to me.  Judaism doesn't consider Islam to be heresy *for non-Jews* (see Shalom's answer), but I don't know if that's what you're asking either.  Would you consider dropping into [chat] so we can help you focus the question?  Thanks.

Comment: @Mawia, we're closing this question pending clarification.  Closing isn't necessarily forever; it's just to prevent people from answering something other than what you intended to ask.

Comment: OK. I'm back. What if I ask _"Does Judaism think Islam is a heresy?"_

Comment: Discussion continued at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9880178#9880178 et seq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maimonides addressed this quite well 800-some years ago.

Jews believe that the version of the faith and law as we have received it is binding upon us. For a Jew to say "I think G-d sent a new prophecy and changed all the laws" or "we got all the laws wrong and here's what they really are instead" would be considered heresy. (It is not, however, idolatry.) (See Maimonides' Laws of Repentance 3:17) Thus we could not accept the law of any prophet who said, for instance, "cooking milk-and-meat together is now permissible."

Islam (in its moderate forms) has brought ethical monotheism to a large percentage of the world's population, which is a wonderful thing. (See Maimonides' Laws of Kings and their Wars, end of Ch. 11) But as for the Jews, who constitute <1% of the world? It's not for us.

Comment: אין מניחין אותן לחדש דת, ולעשות מצוות לעצמן מדעתן, אלא או יהיה גר צדק ויקבל כל המצוות, או יעמוד בתורתו ולא יוסיף ולא יגרע. ואם עסק בתורה, או שבת, או חידש דבר--מכין אותו ועונשין אותו, ומודיעין אותו שהוא חייב מיתה על זה; אבל אינו נהרג.

Comment: it is wrong to say that islam is ok for joyyim because it is not ok. On the contrary they are kofarim for rejecting Torah.joyyim should stick with the Shava MisSwoth Banei NoahH and not add to them which is done by islam

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaAgob, we would consider pure Noahidism better. Rambam is saying, however, that practically, the advent of other monotheistic religions has accomplished some good. (They reached a crowd that standard Noahidism hadn't.)

Comment: no he is saying that it is good because islam thought a form of Noahidism not that it is better than Noahidism. A jeir toshav can only be anointed by a beith din. there cant be jeir toshavim anymore in todays time. however a joy who wants to be a jeir toshav without a beith din it would be better than a muslim

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob Muslims do not 'reject' the Torah outright, they see it as divine scripture. However, they believe that it has been corrupted and superceded by their Quran. To be fair.. if you feel that way about the issue.. perhaps you should preach Noahidism to non-Jews? Just a thought. I can tell you anecdotally that almost no one outside of Judaism has even heard of Noahidism... I don't think they are purposefully 'rejecting' the Torah.

Comment: @A.Concerned.Lurker by saying the quran supersedes it and by saying it is corrupt, that is outright rejected the torah. for the torah says it is eternal. it is a good idea to preach noahidism however, in the state in which the jews are now, it is hard to preach it. as well as jews themselves need some preaching

Answer (score -5):

It is a misnomer to say that Islam is a Abrahamic faith.

While Islam may claim to descend from Avraham, in terms of lessons learned, Islam explicitly rejects Avraham.

In [Quran 60:4](http://www.islamawakened.com/Quran/60/4/default.htm), Abraham is held as an example of excellent conduct (a term used for Mohamed) when he tells his idolatorous father that there is enmity between them.  But then immediately the sentence explains he is NOT an example of conduct, when he prays for forgiveness for his father.

That about sums up Islams view of the value of Abraham.  Only hatred is the good part of Abraham.  Forgiveness is the bad part.

That ain't my Abrahamic faith, than you very much.

Comment: "That about sums up Islams [sic] view." Source? Are there no other relevant passages or interpretations? I know I wouldn't want any pasuk out of context to represent the "Jews' view".

Comment: @DoubleAA Many more issues to raise on Islam, but on this specific issue, this is the key one of interest.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question

Comment: This passage of Quran is not about hatred or forgiveness, it is about a command of Allah. It is not for prophets and believers to pray for the forgiveness of idolaters when it become clear that they have rejected the divine message. According to Muslims, Abraham asked Allah to forgive his father because Abraham was a kind man and also because he had promised his father that he'll pray for him.
Ref.: http://www.al-mawrid.org/pages/questions_english_detail.php?qid=1474&cid=526