# What is God? A definition?

Tags: theology

I wondered "What is God?", a question often turned into "Who or How is God". People often tend to describe who He is instead of defining the word "God" itself. In addition, "God" in this question often refers to the Shem Hameforash, while "God" usually is a translation for the Hebrew title Elohim. But I would like to know in plain English “What is God”? Is it an abstract noun to describe ‘A living force being’?.. there must be a way to define what God is, if we use it all the time to refer to this One and Divine Being which we often call Ein Sof.

Comment: For the Rambam (and I believe in most kabbalistic schools of thought) God can not be positively defined, he can only be known by apophasis (i.e. understanding what He is **not**).

Comment: Indeed @Deuteronomy.Moreh Nevuchim, Ramak, Maharal, R Meir Ibn Gabbai et al. Hashem Himself is beyond all מציאות and definition. Kabbalah claims Hashem created מציאות itself, and so the question seems to be asking about Hashem as Creator, Elokim.

Comment: See the very first chapter of Mishneh Torah.

Comment: See the answers to this related question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26182 (see also here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66670/)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have probably had trouble with this is because it is a subtle, theological question with many caveats and confusions. As you've written, what's the difference between Havaya and Elokim, and how do they relate to the Ein Sof, and Hashem Himself? To answer all this, a lot of learning and study, especially of Jewish Philosophy, Kabbalah and Chassidus, are in order, but the most important thing for everyone to know is He is absolutely One.

However, you do make things easier by simply saying 'in plain english, “What is God”'. This can be answered:

The Rambam gives the definition in the first halacha of Mishneh Torah:

> יְסוֹד הַיְסוֹדוֹת וְעַמּוּד הַחָכְמוֹת לֵידַע שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם מָצוּי
> רִאשׁוֹן. וְהוּא מַמְצִיא כָּל נִמְצָא. וְכָל הַנִּמְצָאִים
> מִשָּׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ וּמַה שֶּׁבֵּינֵיהֶם לֹא נִמְצְאוּ אֶלָּא
> מֵאֲמִתַּת הִמָּצְאוֹ:
>
> The foundation of all foundations and the pillar of wisdom is to know
> that there is a Primary Being who brought into being all existence.
> All the beings of the heavens, the earth, and what is between them
> came into existence only from the truth of His being.

First statement of Derech Hashem:

> מציאות ה׳‎: כל איש מישראל צריך שיאמין וידע שיש שם מצוי ראשון קדמון
> ונצחי והוא שהמציא וממציא כל מה שנמצא במציאות והוא האלוה ב״ה:
>
> The Existence of G-d: Every Jew needs to believe and know that a First
> Being exists. [This Being] is without beginning or end. He brought
> into existence and [constantly] creates everything that is present in
> existence. This [Being] is G-d.

The answer to "What is God" is **the primordial Existence from which all other existence derives**.

This is a question of "מציאות", existence, and Ramchal goes on to define the 6 things we know about His Existence (may He be blessed).

Hashem is not a "what" but a "Who", as you alluded to in your question. "Who" He is, is a more accurate question than "What", which is why the question will often get converted into that. He has no need for a מציאות, and, to the extent we can think of Him in those terms, He is One with His מציאות. It is still disrespectful, bordering on heretical, to think of Him as a "what" and care must be taken in our language.

He Himself is more than a definition. About He Himself, the Alter Rebbe writes in Torah Or, Megilat Ester 99B:

> The fact that all the worlds are brought into existence by God and
> receive their vitality and sustenance from Him - this is not the
> essence of what God is. For as we say "You are who You are before  the
> world was created, and after the world was created" (Adon Olam) -
> exactly the same. Also, if God would not create the worlds, all would
> be the same regarding Him

Maharal writes (Gevurot Hashem Hakdama 2):

> Our sages, of blessed memory, refer to God as "the Holy One, Blessed
> be He"... The term "holy" denotes an entity that is apart and removed.
> [It therefore describes God,] because God is abstract in the most
> ultimate sense of abstraction. But precisely because God is the
> ultimate abstraction, there is nothing that is excluded from Him.
>
> When something has a definition, and is distinguished by certain
> characteristics, that same definition will exclude form it things that
> are outside of that definition. But because God has no definition at
> all, nothing is excluded from Him. Therefore, He knows everything and
> can do anything. All this is because God is not defined by any
> specific definitions, therefore, everything comes from Him.

There is a course by the JLI on "What is God". Rav Manis Friedman gives a great class on it, recorded [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5An6jsH4tA), and well worth a watch.

I will note, we say 3 times a day "Hashem Echad". Hashem is One. Something to contemplate, and study.

Answer (score 0):

In Tanakh, Elohim is always Aware while hiding among humanity to collect earthly feedback from any zakar or nekevah (Bereshit 1:27). When Sarah laughed within her head, Elohim read her thoughts (Bereshit 18). - “Yihyeh Hoveh Hayah” is an Invincible & Invisible Spirit shaping humanity constantly based on our First & Last memories (Yeshayahu 48). > “Elohim” (El/Angels/Judges) represented Consciousness of ancient Yisrael (Tehillim 82). As Oseh of Shalom & Ra (Yeshayahu 45:7), HaShem always creates darkness first before forming light to allow lies (Devarim 13:4, Yirmiyahu 23) which test His souls’ (Yechezkel 18) ability to truly live by loving chesed, compassion, selflessness and tzedakah (Mishlei 19:17).

Comment: This answer is very deep. It could benefit from a few Rabbinic sources that state the connections between the pasukim and the statements you've made, as well as a few extra explanations such as the link between Hashem "representing" our "Consciousness" in Tehillim 82, the link between Yeshaya 48:12 and "memories", Yechezkel 18 and "tests", plus the "earthly feedback" connection with Tzelem Elokim. These ideas are very profound and extra reading for them all would be great. Thanks for this contribution tzaddik

Answer (score -1):

"I am that I am." Exodus 3:14. There is nothing to compare Him to. He is not like anything else. Isaiah 46:5,9.

He is in all places at all times (Jeremiah 23:24, Psalm 139:7-10) yet His presence can be in a place: the pillar of fire and cloud, the Holy of Holies, Mount Sinai. He wrestled with Jacob, ate with Abraham, spoke to Moses "face to face, as a man speaks to his friend" (Exodus 33:11), spoke to Samson's parents, killed 185,000 Assyrians whose general dared compare Him to the "gods" of the Gentiles, appeared to Ezekiel and Isaiah and Daniel in visions where they saw the "likeness" of His appearance-- yet no man can see Him and live (Exodus 33:20), therefore none of them saw Him exactly as He is. He is not like us (Psalm 50:21): He doesn't think like us and His ways are not like ours (Isaiah 55:8-9).

Therefore the fear of YHWH is His treasure. The fear of YHWH is the beginning of knowledge and wisdom. The friendship of YHWH is with those who fear Him, and He makes known to them His covenant.

Job thought he knew about Hashem. Indeed, even Hashem said Job spoke rightly about Him in contrast to his companions (Job 42:7). Yet when Hashem questioned Job, asking Job if he knew any of the depths of His wisdom, knowledge, and power, Job laid his hand on his mouth, ashamed of how he had boasted in what he thought he knew, and said he would speak no more. (Job 40:4-5) The climactic statement of Job is a banner for the wise: “I know that you can do all things, and that no purpose of yours can be thwarted. ‘Who is this that hides counsel without knowledge?’ Therefore I have uttered what I did not understand, things too wonderful for me, which I did not know. ‘Hear, and I will speak; I will question you, and you make it known to me.’ I had heard of you by the hearing of the ear, but now my eye sees you; therefore I despise myself, and repent in dust and ashes.”Job 42:2‭-‬6.

Man does not know the answer to your question. It can't be known by beings so small like ourselves. Hashem is so very set-apart, and we are but dust, a flower of the field that perishes, a wisp of smoke that is but for a moment. All that we know are the bits He has chosen to reveal; the hidden things belong to Him (Deuteronomy 29:29).

"With the humble is wisdom." Proverbs 11:2.

"O YHWH, my heart is not lifted up; my eyes are not raised too high; I do not occupy myself with things too great and too marvelous for me. But I have calmed and quieted my soul, like a weaned child with its mother; like a weaned child is my soul within me. O Israel, hope in YHWH from this time forth and forevermore." Psalm 131:1‭-‬3