# Are Allah and Hashem one and the same?

Tags: names, islam

Most Jews do not refer to G-d as Allah as they don't speak any Arabic, but names aside, does Judaism consider Islam's Allah the same entity as the G-d of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob?

Comment: Rabbi Ovadya Yosef in Hebrew was "Abdullah" in Arabic.

Comment: This seems off-topic as comparative religion, as well as a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14461/ which was closed for the same reason (or rather, its 2012 equivalent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many Jews in Arab countries prior to coming to Israel used the word "Allah" to refer to God in everyday language in Arabic.  Clearly though we do not believe that the "Allah" of the Quran is the same God that gave us the Torah as we do not follow Islam.  Rambam referred to Muhammad as a false prophet and an insane man.  In the Mishneh Torah (see: Hilkhot Melakhim), Rambam indicated that nevertheless Muhammad was part of God's plan of preparing the world for the coming of the Moshiach by transforming "*the peoples to a purer language that they all will call upon the name of God and serve Him with one purpose*":

> ואם יעמוד מלך מבית דויד הוגה בתורה ועוסק במצות כדויד אביו כפי תורה
>   שבכתב ושבעל פה ויכוף כל ישראל לילך בה ולחזק בדקה וילחם מלחמות ה' הרי
>   זה בחזקת שהוא משיח אם עשה והצליח ובנה מקדש במקומו וקבץ נדחי ישראל הרי
>   זה משיח בודאי ויתקן את העולם כולו לעבוד את ה' ביחד שנאמר כי אז אהפוך
>   אל עמים שפה ברורה לקרוא כולם בשם ה' ולעבדו שכם אחד. ואם לא הצליח עד כה
>   או נהרג בידוע שאינו זה שהבטיחה עליו תורה והרי הוא ככל מלכי בית דויד
>   השלמים והכשרים שמתו ולא העמידו הקדוש ברוך הוא אלא לנסות בו רבים שנאמר
>   ומן המשכילים יכשלו לצרוף בהם ולברר וללבן עד עת קץ כי עוד למועד. אף
>   ישוע הנצרי שדימה שיהיה משיח ונהרג בבית דין כבר נתנבא בו דניאל שנאמר
>   ובני פריצי עמך ינשאו להעמיד חזון ונכשלו וכי יש מכשול גדול מזה שכל
>   הנביאים דברו שמשיח גואל ישראל ומושיעם ומקבץ נדחיהם ומחזק מצוותן וזה
>   גרם לאבד ישראל בחרב ולפזר שאריתם ולהשפילם ולהחליף התורה ולהטעות רוב
>   העולם לעבוד אלוה מבלעדי ה'. אך מחשבות בורא עולם אין כוח באדם להשיגם כי
>   לא דרכינו דרכיו ולא מחשבותינו מחשבותיו וכל הדברים האלו של ישוע הנצרי
>   ושל זה **הישמעאלי** שעמד אחריו אינן אלא לישר דרך למלך המשיח ולתקן העולם
>   כולו לעבוד את ה' ביחד שנאמר כי אז אהפוך אל אחד עמים שפה ברורה לקרוא
>   כולם בשם ה' לעבדו שכם אחד. כיצד כבר נתמלא העולם מדברי המשיח ומדברי
>   התורה ומדברי המצוות ופשטו דברים אלו באיים רחוקים ובעמים רבים ערלי לב
>   והם נושאים ונותנים בדברים אלו ובמצוות התורה אלו אומרים מצוות אלו אמת
>   היו וכבר בטלו בזמן הזה ולא היו נוהגות לדורות ואלו אומרים דברים נסתרים
>   יש בהן ואינן כפשוטן וכבר בא משיח וגילה נסתריהם וכשיעמוד המלך המשיח
>   באמת ויצליח וירום וינשא מיד הם כולם חוזרים ויודעים ששקר נחלו אבותיהם
>   ושנביאיהם ואבותיהם הטעום:
>
> If a king will arise from the House of David who diligently
>   contemplates the Torah and observes its mitzvot as prescribed by the
>   Written Law and the Oral Law as David, his ancestor, will compel all
>   of Israel to walk in (the way of the Torah) and rectify the breaches
>   in its observance, and fight the wars of God, we may, with assurance,
>   consider him Mashiach.
>
> If he succeeds in the above, builds the Temple in its place, and
>   gathers the dispersed of Israel, he is definitely the Mashiach.
>
> He will then improve the entire world, motivating all the nations to
>   serve God together, as Tzephaniah 3:9 states: 'I will transform the
>   peoples to a purer language that they all will call upon the name of
>   God and serve Him with one purpose.'
>
> If he did not succeed to this degree or was killed, he surely is not
>   the redeemer promised by the Torah. Rather, he should be considered as
>   all the other proper and complete kings of the Davidic dynasty who
>   died. God caused him to arise only to test the many, as Daniel 11:35
>   states: 'And some of the wise men will stumble, to try them, to
>   refine, and to clarify until the appointed time, because the set time
>   is in the future.'
>
> Jesus of Nazareth who aspired to be the Mashiach and was executed by
>   the court was also alluded to in Daniel's prophecies, as ibid. 11:14
>   states: 'The vulgar among your people shall exalt themselves in an
>   attempt to fulfill the vision, but they shall stumble.'
>
> Can there be a greater stumbling block than Christianity? All the
>   prophets spoke of Mashiach as the redeemer of Israel and their savior
>   who would gather their dispersed and strengthen their observance of
>   the mitzvot. In contrast, Christianity caused the Jews to be slain by
>   the sword, their remnants to be scattered and humbled, the Torah to be
>   altered, and the majority of the world to err and serve a god other
>   than the Lord.
>
> Nevertheless, the intent of the Creator of the world is not within the
>   power of man to comprehend, for His ways are not our ways, nor are His
>   thoughts, our thoughts. **Ultimately, all the deeds of Jesus of
>   Nazareth and that Ishmaelite who arose after him will only serve to
>   prepare the way for Mashiach's coming and the improvement of the
>   entire world, motivating the nations to serve God together as
>   Tzephaniah 3:9 states: 'I will transform the peoples to a purer
>   language that they all will call upon the name of God and serve Him
>   with one purpose.'**
>
> How will this come about? The entire world has already become filled
>   with the mention of Mashiach, Torah, and mitzvot. These matters have
>   been spread to the furthermost islands to many stubborn-hearted
>   nations. They discuss these matters and the mitzvot of the Torah,
>   saying: 'These mitzvot were true, but were already negated in the
>   present age and are not applicable for all time.'
>
> Others say: 'Implied in the mitzvot are hidden concepts that can not
>   be understood simply. The Mashiach has already come and revealed those
>   hidden truths.'
>
> When the true Messianic king will arise and prove successful, his
>   position becoming exalted and uplifted, they will all return and
>   realize that their ancestors endowed them with a false heritage and
>   their prophets and ancestors caused them to err.

Comment: "Clearly though we do not believe that the "Allah" of the Quran is the same God that gave us the Torah as we do not follow Islam". That doesn't follow.  It's like saying George Washington who chopped down a cherry tree is not the same George Washington who was president because the the cherry tree story didn't actually hapoen.

Comment: To believe in the Allah of the Quran is to believe that His prophet was Mohammed and that He has overriden the Torah.  Thus, I do not believe that the words of Allah in the Quran are the words of the same God that I worship.

Comment: @MordechaibenYosef No, one can believe in the entity a person is referring to, without believing in what the person is saying.